# Como pasar una funcion de un componente a otro

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, props, dialog

tengo un componentes que es home.js y otro que es modal.js
En modal guardo lo que es un popup que se activa al hacer click en una imagen.
ademas de pasar el modal necesito que una funcion especifica que es la que abre el modal
Creo que pase bien las props pero al clicar ya no se activa nose

Home.js

```
const galery = useSelector((state) => state.search);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [valor, setValor] = useState("");
  const [resultados, setResultados] = useState([]);
  

  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
    const [imag, setImg] = useState("");

    function closeModal() {
        setIsOpen(false);
      }
    
      const openModal = (e)=> {
        setIsOpen(true);
        setImg(e.target);
      }

return(
<Modal
      openModal={openModal}
      closeModal={closeModal}
      imag={imag}
      isOpen={isOpen}
      />
      
  <section className="w-full gap-0 sm:columns-2 md:columns-3 xl:columns-4 2xl:columns-5 3xl:columns-6">
    {galery.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <form onSubmit={savePhoto} key={index} className='relative'>
          <button className='absolute left-5 top-3 bg-gray shadow-md'>Guardar</button>
          <img
          name='photo'
          className="object-cover p-2"
          src={item.urls.regular}
          alt={item.alt_description}
        />
        </form>
      );
    })}
  </section>
```

)

Modal.js

```
    function Modal({openModal, closeModal, imag, isOpen}) {
    
        return (
            <Transition 
            appear
            show={isOpen}
            as={Fragment}
          >
            <Dialog as="div" className="fixed inset-1/3 z-10" onClose={closeModal}>
              <Transition.Child
                as={Fragment}
           

  leaveFrom="opacity-100"
            leaveTo="opacity-0"
          >
            <div className="fixed inset-0 bg-black bg-opacity-25" />
          </Transition.Child>

          <Dialog.Panel className="w-full max-w-full transform overflow-hidden rounded-2xl bg-white p-6 text-left align-middle shadow-xl transition-all">
            <div className="w-full">
              <img
                className="flex justify-center rounded-md border border-transparent bg-blue-100 px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-blue-900 hover:bg-blue-200 focus:outline-none focus-visible:ring-2 focus-visible:ring-blue-500 focus-visible:ring-offset-2"
                onClick={closeModal}
                src={imag.src}
                alt={imag.alt}
              />
            </div>
          </Dialog.Panel>
        </Dialog>
      </Transition>
    )
```

}

Comment: ok cuando hace clic no se activa el modal?  ya intentaste  !isOpen

Comment: me abriste la mente jaja, fue tonteria mia que se me olvido agregarle el onclick a la foto, que se lo quite haciendo pruebas gracias xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error tonto mio no añadir al mapeo que hago a galery en la etiqueta img poner el atributo

`onClick={openModal}`